# Erlang port driver compatible both with R15B and pre-R15B

Tags: c, erlang, 64-bit

Given the changes described in http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/erl_driver.html#rewrites_for_64_bits, is it reasonable to try to keep a port driver compatible with both new and old interfaces using `#if/#else` preprocessor directives?

Answer (score 0):

I think it mostly depends on how exactly the port driver is going to be used.

If it's a part of some specific project that is running R15B and not planning to return to older versions - then why to bother? In other cases like trying to build some kind of library for usage in unknown environments it certainly can help with compatibility.

Comment: Yes, it's a library. The question is whether it's likely to work or end up too hard to maintain.